# Ghost post_title from my WP LOOP script

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, while-loop, echo

The code below is displaying the title in black text before it displays blue title with hyperlink under it.

I only want the link to appear.

```
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    // The 2nd Loop
    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();
                 if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate)
                continue;
                $permalink = get_the_permalink($query2->post->ID);
                $ID = $post->ID;
                $titleAtribute = the_title_attribute();
                $title = get_the_title();
        echo '<h2 id="post-' .$ID.' ">
                <a href="'.$permalink.'" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to '.$permalink.' ">
                   '.$title.'</a></h2>';
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

For example, on my website: http://skkelti.cz/, the following text appears in black above the link with the same text:

> -Martin Davídek ml. : „Fanoušci jsou vždy to, co vás žene kupředu“-

Where is this coming from and what do I need to do to stop it from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `the_title_attribute()`. This is displaying the value directly instead of returning it.

The function accepts `echo` in $args to specify whether to display or return the value. The default value is true (to display it), so pass false to return the value e.g.:

```
$titleAtribute = the_title_attribute('echo=0');
```

Comment: okay, if I am not going to display it, why am I supossed to have it in code? :O Thanks for advice

Comment: You don't want to display it *immediately* - that's whats happening now. What you want to do is to get the value and save it in the variable called `$titleAtribute`, so you can use that to display it whenever you want. Its just like `$title = get_the_title();` - you don't display that on the screen at that point, you save it into the `$title` variable and then use `$title` in the next line when you are creating the link. (You don't actually use `$titleAtribute` at all in the code you included but maybe you use it somewhere else).